# How do I link a domain verified Google Search Console site to Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I'm trying to connect a Google Search Console property to Google Analytics.

It's supposed to be as easy as: `Admin > Property Settings > Add a Search Console Site` (that's been verified).

This particular site has been domain verified in Search Console. So I'm finding it's not that easy.

[This thread](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Account-Access/Verified-site-still-not-appearing-in-Google-Search-Console/td-p/1940453) says that linking a domain verified search console site to analytics is not possible. You have to add the site as a URL-prefix.

My questions:

- If the site has already been domain verified, do I have to first remove the domain verified site from Search Console and then re-add as a URL-prefix?
- I tried simply adding the site as a URL-prefix and it did not work.
  Once added as a URL-prefix I see this:

  [image]

  So even though the site has been added as a URL-prefix, Google
  Analytics still won't me link to the property. The website still does
  not appear in Google Analytics as a Search Console property even when
  added as a URL-prefix.
- If I remove the domain, will we lose all historical data in Search Console?
- Have any of you run into this issue? How have you worked around it?

I have to figure this out for a large client and don't want to drop the ball. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't have to remove the domain. In Search Console Parameters > Validation details, you will be able to select another validation method which should allow you to associate your accounts.

Comment: @gael You can't switch the verification method for domain properties because they only support DNS verification.

Comment: You don't need to remove the domain property, you can have both a domain property and a prefix property at the same time.  If you remove the domain property you will lose historical data and all the other advantages of having a domain property.  Just create a second prefix property that you use only for GA for now.  Hopefully Google will soon allow you to link domain properties to GA.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks so much. I tried that. I added the site as an additional prefix but the site still doesn't appear as an option I can link to in GA. I can see other properties from other clients, but not this one.

Comment: Can you switch to the old search console and add it from there?